# Python/Matplotlib: How can I display an image according to a specific (x, y) position?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to wrote an astrology application. This application plot a natal chart for a given time and location.

The below image is the correct image. But what I want to do this, using sign symbols instead of names.

[image: With sign names]

And the below image is from when images were used instead of text.

[image: With sign symbols]

I did not understand why such components like "house numbers" are changed. The codes that create both text and image have no effect on "house numbers".

Can you help me?

**Edit:** For whole codes and images, visit this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g0d71rtwfqh03w9/AACfweAhLAutAHVQayE4wrA_a?dl=0).

```
def draw_sign_names(self):
    asc = self.house_cusps()[1]
    for i, j in enumerate(self.SIGNS):
        end = 30 - (asc % 30) + 180
        start = end - 30
        start += (30 * i)
        end += (30 * i)
        if start > 360:
            start -= 360
        if end > 360:
            end -= 360
        if start > 330:
            midpoint = (start + end + 360) / 2
        else:
            midpoint = (start + end) / 2
        if midpoint > 360:
            midpoint -= 360
        _x1, _y1 = self.x_y(angle=midpoint, r1=480, r2=400)
        img = plt.imread(f"{self.sign_pos()[1][i]}.png")
        plt.imshow(img, aspect="auto", interpolation="gaussian", extent=[_x1[0], _x1[1], _y1[1], _y1[0]])
        # plt.text(sum(_x1) / 2, sum(_y1) / 2, self.sign_pos()[1][i], color="black", size=8, rotation=-10)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what house numbers are (the numbers in the sectors with the 6 in a weird place?) and you're not showing the code for them, which makes it difficult to help. But I guess you noticed your axes are flipped between both images, right?

Comment: Yes, 6 was not on it's right place at the previous image. I changed the images. Yes, I noticed that. And I wonder why such a strange result like that was produced. Also the images are distorted.

Comment: Again, your question (“can you help me?”) is not clear. What is the problem with your code?
But to simplify, matplotlib is designed to plot mathematical graphs, it is not primarily a drawing image manipulation tool. As such, the graph elements (lines, dot, numbers, images), defined in some logical coordinates (the one shown on the axes), are placed in the image based on a projection and coordinate mapping. You might want to take a look, for instance, at: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html
By the way, are you rotating your text to simulate italics?

Comment: I put the codes here that are related to adding text or image to the graphic. Yes, I know matplotlib is designed to plot mathematical graphs. But the graphic that I draw also contains some mathematical calculations. As you can see on the images, I have no problem with drawing angled lines in matplotlib. The problem appears, when I want to add "sign images" to the graph, as I said in my first post.  I rotated the text which contain numbers to zoom out them from the lines. But the text that contains sign names will be removed if I solve this problem.

Comment: The problem was solved by using tkinter instead of matplotlib.